# How do I login to okta without redirecting to the okta website for authentication?

Tags: android, android-activity, okta, okta-api, android-authenticator

I am using the below code :

```
https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-android-example/commit/5d01efe98b9a73937c8eeec92797117ad1f8a72b
```

for testing okta authentication, but it redirects me to the okta website for authentication and i would like to make it such that I don't get redirected for authentication, but remotely authenticate based on the credentials I enter in my app which upon verification and successful login send me over to my app dashboard.
Currently based on the above code, i am getting redirected to okta, i enter my credentials and then it kicks me back to the app which is not a very good flow. Anyone has any experience with this or any ideas how I can avoid redirection or any good examples online I can test out with ?

Comment: Hey Marissa! I work @ Okta and manage our Android SDKs (etc). Can you clarify what your app needs to do? What is the app dashboard you are trying to redirect users to - the Okta app dashboard (`https://{yourCompany}.okta.com/app/UserHome`), or something else you have built? Feel free to post in our developer forum (https://devforum.okta.com), might be a better fit there than Stack Overflow. Cheers!

Comment: Or, I might be over-thinking your question. :) Are you just trying to build an app that does not use a browser for sign-in, but rather uses a custom sign-in view/fragment inside the app to gather credentials?

Comment: @NateBarbettini , yup I am just trying to bypass the web re-direction thing for authentication. Just entering the credentials onto my app and clicking on login should take me straight into the app and the authentication should happen in the background with okta rather than getting redirected to okta webpage for authentication and then kicking back to the app after authentication. is there a sample for android app that shows this scenario? any easy way to do this?

Comment: Got it! Yep, that is possible with a little bit of extra code. We are building a sample for it right now and will release it soon. It will be here: https://github.com/okta/samples-android

Comment: @NateBarbettini do you have any idea how long it will take to release? I am  planning to release my app early next month and need this component asap

Comment: It's live now! See https://github.com/okta/samples-android/

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is standard OAuth2 flow which is designed to ensure user never enter their credentials directly in the application. The intention here is to avoid your application being able to capture/cache the user credentials, which is really what the credential owner ( the user ) wants. OAuth2 is designed around redirecting the user to their identity provider, entering their credentials there, and authorizing the application to access resourcs on their behalf. It's a standard pattern these days.

However, for 1st party applications where there is trust there's an existing OAuth2 flow that will do what you want called the resource owner password flow. I'm not recommending you implement it, but it will allow you to capture the user credentials locally and recieve appropriate tokens in the response.
https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/password